# To make comma separated single row into multiple rows if exceeds the specified size of the length in SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having single comma separated row of column as mentioned below and I need to split it into multiple rows if it exceeds the specified length

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
      ID                          Name                     Length_Name 
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
      1                David,John,James,Mary,Bryan            27
      2                Mike,Boucher,Pollard                   20
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Here suppose the Name column value's crosses the length of 12 it needs to mention like as below

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
      ID                          Name                     Length_Name 
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
      1                      David,John                      10
      1                      James,Mary                      10
      1                      Bryan                           5
      2                      Mike,Boucher                    12
      2                      Pollard                         7
--------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Please, if anyone knows solution, kindly comment it.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple names in a comma-delimited string.

Comment: Hi, in this context the data model looks wrong to me too, if all names in one row should be related in any way, use a second table and connect them by a key. Sure, there could be a way to cover your question direct, but i will guess it leads to other problems later!

Comment: Tag says MySql, title says SQL Server. These are two different products...